# write avg subtotal in filtered list "in-line" with month

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a list of values, where want to calculate the average for each month based on the `subtotal(101)` function. Each month has a different amount of values (e.g. 5 values for March, 17 for July). (see table below)

```
Value  Month  MonthAvg
----------------------
34     Jan  
32     Jan 
34     Feb
22     Feb
45     Feb   
71     Mar
80     Mar
101    Mar
```

My current code loops through all month in the autofiltered list (jan - dec) and writes the average to an array, which then  outputs those values to the sheet into a column with the corresponding month.

```
Dim lMonthCounter As Integer
Dim arrMonthAvg(11) As Single
Dim wksA as Worksheet

For lMonthCounter = 21 To 32
      
     wksA.Range("a1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=lMonthCounter, Operator:=11, Criteria2:=0, SubField:=0   
     arrMonthAvg(lMonthCounter - 21) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(101, wksA.Range("F:F"))       
     
Next lMonthCounter
```

Instead of outputting those values to cells in the sheet, i want them "in-line" with the correspoding month to use them in a graph as indicated below:

```
Value  Month  MonthAvg
-----------------------
34     Jan    33
32     Jan    33
34     Feb    33.66
22     Feb    33.66
45     Feb    33.66
71     Mar    84
80     Mar    84
101    Mar    84
```

Any pointers how i can write these average values to the filtered cells? The values for each month are not necessarily in asc. or desc. order by date (meaning, it could be that June is followed by March) if thats relevant to the task.

Comment: any reason you have to use SUBTOTAL(101) and not the AVERAGEIF function?

Comment: Tbh. I haven't given much thought to using a different formula, since this worked for me. Would this help my issue?

Comment: yes - because you pass it your entire range and it works out the average just for the months with the same name. You'll want something like =AVERAGEIF(B:B,B2,A:A) assuming that your months are in column B and your values are in column A

Comment: So, instead of using the subtotal i would use AVERAGEIF as a formula in the corresponding cell? - EDIT: Thanks, that worked like a treat!